# i want to remove the coma in this column which contains 1000 separators while programming in R3.4.2

Tags: r

28-Nov-17   984.5       153072
27-Nov-17   997.5       172456
24-Nov-17   1,009.95    491269
23-Nov-17   991.4       311986
22-Nov-17   966.3       81,870

convert the second and third column as integers . I have 250 rows

i am able to convert as characters, but when i use as.integers it gives NA for those which has 1000s separators

Comment: You can use `gsub` i.e. `as.numeric(gsub(",", "", df$col2))`

Comment: as.numeric(gsub(",", "", myfilename))
NAs introduced by coercion[1] NA NA NA   is what i get

Comment: I assume that there is only `,` as non-numeric part.  If there are other characters, you may need to remove it i.e. `as.numeric(gsub(",", "", "1,001.50"))#
[1] 1001.5`

Comment: data.frame': 245 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date  : chr  "8-Dec-17" "7-Dec-17" "6-Dec-17" "5-Dec-17" ...
 $ price : chr  "1,001.55" "1,000.10" "990.4" "984.4" ...
 $ Volume: chr  "1,95,292" "2,19,237" "1,42,237" "3,09,135" ...
 
> as.numeric(gsub(",", "", infy1))
NAs introduced by coercion[1] NA NA NA
> #as.numeric(gsub(",", "", infy1$price))
> str(infy1)
'data.frame': 245 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Date  : chr  "8-Dec-17"  ...
 $ price : chr  "1,001.55"" ...
 $ Volume: chr  "1,95,292"   i need t change price and volume as integer which contain coma

Comment: Ohh, you are applying `gsub` into the entire dataset.  It should be to `infy1$yourcolumn`